# MySQL counting elements without using count(*)

Tags: mysql, count

I'm practicing MySQL for an upcoming exam and need some help.

I have this db:
USER(Code, Name, Surname, Age)
THEATRE(Name, City, Capacity)
SUBSCRIPTION(ID, UserCode, TheatreName, Amount)

With these referential integrity constraints:

SUBSCRIPTION.UserCode->USER.Code
SUBSCRIPTION.TheatreName->THEATRE.Name

For exercise I need to write the query which determines code, name and surname of the users older than 50 and who has more than one subscription WITHOUT using the COUNT function.
I know that maybe a self-join could help but I really don't know how. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

<s>[`EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):</s>

```
SELECT u.Code, u.Name, u.Surname
FROM USER u
WHERE u.Age > 50
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM SUBSCRIPTION s WHERE u.Code = s.UserCode
)
```

Or [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.Code, u.Name, u.Surname
FROM USER u
JOIN SUBSCRIPTION s
ON u.Code = s.UserCode
WHERE u.Age > 50
```

***Edited:***

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.Code, u.Name, u.Surname
FROM USER u
JOIN SUBSCRIPTION s1
ON u.Code = s1.UserCode
JOIN SUBSCRIPTION s2
ON u.Code = s2.UserCode
WHERE s1.ID <> s2.ID
AND u.Age > 50
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand this: 
SELECT 1 FROM SUBSCRIPTION s WHERE u.Code = s.UserCode

Where do the "1" come from?

Comment: "1" is meaningless, you can replace it with any column in table `SUBSCRIPTION `, check the manual of `EXISTS`. Btw, does it work?

Comment: I think you miss the second point of the question: I need to select users who are older than 50 AND have more than one subscription. Your queries satisfy only the first request.

Comment: @user3515916 Did you just run there two queries? If they do not work, then I update my answer, if they do, then I can explain to you how it works. You can not just "I think...", run it and tell me the result.

Comment: Yes I run the queries and they return the users older than 50 with at least one subscription which is not what the problem requires because I need to select only the ones who have MORE than 1 subscription.

Comment: Now it works but you need to change the last row which is "AND u.Age > 50" not "WHERE u.Age>50" (in your way I got a syntax error). But I don't really understand your solution...nevertheless, you have my deepest gratitude :)

Comment: @user3515916 Some explanation for the answer, `s1` and `s2` both match the row in table `user` with `Code = UserCode`, if `SUBSCRIPTION` only have one record, then  `s1.ID <> s2.ID` will not match, so only if there are more than one record in `SUBSCRIPTION` for each user can be matched, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest way to accomplish this is to essentially redesign the count function into a sum function with a case statement thusly:

```
SELECT
  u.NAME
, u.SURNAME
, u.CODE
, SUM(CASE WHEN t.SUBSCRIPTION IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TOTAL_SUBSCRIPTIONS -- IDENTICAL TO COUNT(s.*)
, COUNT(s.*) -- SHOULD MATCH THE TOTAL_SUBSCRIPTIONS
FROM
USER AS u
LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIPTION AS s
ON  u.CODE = s.USERCODE
-- LEFT JOIN THEATRE AS t -- commented because I don't see a requirement for this table to be brought forward.
-- ON  s.THEATRENAME = t.NAME
WHERE u.AGE > 50
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t.SUBSCRIPTION IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
```

Without using a CASE statment:

```
SELECT
      u.NAME
    , u.SURNAME
    , u.CODE
    , SUM( (select SUM(1) from SUBSCRIPTION WHERE s.USERCODE = u.CODE) ) as TOTAL_SUBSCRIPTIONS -- IDENTICAL TO COUNT(s.*)
    FROM
    USER AS u
    WHERE u.AGE > 50
```

Comment: Thank you but we didn't studied the 'case' function so we're not supposed to use that. I believe the previous solution is what the prof. has in his mind.

Comment: Ahh, I see. What other functions did you study because perhaps there is an expectation that you will use one of those functions in this. I believe you could also sum( subquery ) and get the same answer.

Comment: We studied pretty much all the basic functions except the scalar functions. So, yes, we can use the SUM. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the first one is more suitable for my purposes as it fits the professor's indications, but thanks anyway for your help :)